# Deploy custom Navigation / SiteMap via Feature?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, navigation

You can customize the navigation in SP2010 via Site Settings > Navigation:

[image]

How would I go ahead and define a simple (!) navigation myself and deploy with via feature? I don't really want to create a custom master page - just like I would do via the frontend: Add two links to the menu and I'm happy.

I read about a [custom site map provider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/spnav.aspx) and using a [custom xml file and reference it in the web.config](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/05/17/sharepoint-implementing-a-custom-navigation-scheme-across-multiple-site-collections-for-the-%E2%80%9Cnon-developer%E2%80%9D/), but I cannot believe it is not easier to simply modify some existing links in the global navigation and add some new ones - basically create my own menu.

Let's go with an example:

```
Global Navigation
    Custom Folder
        Products --> lists/products
        More News --> lists/morenews
        Entertainment --> lists/entertainment
    Another Folder
        Somethingelse --> somethingelse.aspx
```

How would I go about and deploy this to my site and replace the global navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I'm looking for the [SPWeb.Navigation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.navigation.aspx). I can easily add links to the global navigation and the quick launch by using the `AddToQuickLaunch` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.addtoquicklaunch.aspx)) method.

Microsoft even has a MSDN entry for what I was looking for: [Adding Links to Quick Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx).

Once you're on track you find more information:

- [Best way to programmatically create/maintain SharePoint Quick Launch menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041775/best-way-to-programmatically-create-maintain-sharepoint-quick-launch-menu)
- [Beware of deleting Global Navigation nodes in SPWeb.Navigation.GlobalNodes](https://statto1974.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/beware-of-deleting-global-navigation-nodes-in-spwebnavigationglobalnodes/)

So now I just have to add my custom navigation via a Feature Receiver and all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, one option would be to use asp:repeaters in the masterpage to pull in data from the global navigation. First you need to setup something in the masterpage that will pull in data from their built in navigation (site settings>navigation). Then you can style it however you want in the master page. So now if you add more entries into the navigation, they will appear the same in the navigation.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/

Answer (score -1):

I would create an event receiver for your feature that runs the code you require.
[Here](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/How+to+add+a+Feature+Receiver+to+a+Feature) and [here](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/16/updating-the-navigation-settings-in-a-publishing-site/) are a couple of links to get you started.

Comment: Yes, I would add an event receiver as well. My question aims for particular code though - where is the navigation defined, how do I change it. The first link you provide is about a feature receiver - not related. The second link explains how to include subsites in the navigation, but not how to include custom links etc...