# areanavigationsettings.aspx Programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've been messing with SPNavigationProvider, PublishingWebs, and etc for the past few days and I can not figure out how to move a node in /_layouts/areanavigationsettings.aspx programmatically.

The node I need to move is in the list of the Global Navigation, but when I query the SPPublihsingWeb.GlobalNavigationNodes it is not listed. When I call IncludeInNavigation() on the web I need in GlobalNavigationNodes, there is no change.

I'm doing this through a Feature Activation if that makes any difference.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to do similar things I just did: [Deploy custom Navigation / SiteMap via Feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407153/deploy-custom-navigation-sitemap-via-feature).

Instead of using the Publishing Site, why not use the `SPWeb.Navigation`?

Check out the following MSDN entry on [Adding Links through Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476607%28v=office.12%29.aspx) - just iterate over the Children of SPWeb.Navigation and you will find your link and will be able to modify it.